# issues with apache when enable php7 and php5

Tags: php, apache

Could you help me? My apache has php5 and php7. The problem here I only can enable one by one at the same time. Is there any ways to run both them at the point? Thank you much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple possibilities on working with multiple php interpreters. it depends on how you want to use those php interpreters. for example: you want to use php5 for webapp and php7 for the other webapp, so you can do this via vhosts: https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=6615 this should help.
in the vhosts you can configure, how the php files should be handled - be careful of the php environment variables that needs to be correctly set up.

tell me how you want to use both of the versions - your use case - and i might be able to help you a bit better.

Comment: Thank you. But I was enable the two mod then error when restart apache2.

Comment: you can check your apache config files with following command: /pathtoyourapachebin/httpd.exe -t       then you should get the errormessage and you could tell me whats wrong, maybe you used a wrong php version or you did include the php modules the wrong way?

Comment: cannot load two modules at the same time.

Comment: show us the lines in your apache conf, how you load your modules. and did you check on the link i posted? may be of help how to load and include them

Comment: LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.so
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>